AWS EFS Metered Size is significantly larger than amount actually stored on disk
On the Metered size tab of my AWS EFS file system it says I am using 544.22 GB
Total size 544.22 GiB
Size in Standard 438.47 GiB (81%)
Size in IA 105.75 GiB (19%)

I found this value suspicious as I copy the data to an S3 bucket and it is 87GB.
Running this du -h --max-depth=1 command on the EFS machine confirms this.
[user]# du -h --max-depth=1
86G     ./foldera
87G     .

Running this du -sh command on the EFS machine gives this.
[user]# du -sh
87G
At first I thought it may be that i have a lot of small files that get counted as 4KB but I only have a couple hundred small files. Any suggestions why the variance?

WHat is the result of du -sh executed from the same place as above command?

Could this be related to versioning or snapshots within AWS?

hi @RomeoNinov i have added the result to your request in the body of the question ..it is the same size as the du -h command

@DanielK I don't have versioning on in EFS .. i don't think it works like S3 where versioning is a bigger deal .. I don't have any other snapshots in there .. just the raw files
